# Can global variable be used to call function?

Tags: python-2.7, variables, module

SEFC.py:

```
import time
import traceback
import platform

sefc_verbose = False
obj_sefc = None

class CSEFC():

  def __init__(self):
      self.fp_platform = False
      self.bbu_platform = False
      return 

   def __del__(self):
      return

   def ipmi_cmd_trace(self):
       return False
```

KCS.py:

```
import SEFC as sefc

class CKCS(CLogger):

  def __init__(self, str_ip = None, int_port = _DEFAULT_ATRAGON_PORT):
      CLogger.__init__(self)
      self.obj_json_client = None

   def send_ipmi_target(self, targetstr, raw_request, int_retry = 3):
       if sefc.obj_sefc.ipmi_cmd_trace():
        ##do stuff
```

I am reading code written by someone else.I can't seem to understand in `if sefc.obj_sefc.ipmi_cmd_trace():` `obj_sefc` is used to call `ipmi_cmd_trace()` function. `sefc_obj` is a global variable I belive. But this code should not work. Also, I doubt my programming ability. This code seems to compile and work for others. Is this correct? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

With just the code you've shown, you're right, it won't work, since `obj_sefc` is `None` in the `SEFC` module. However, I suspect that some other code that you haven't shown that creates an instance of the `CSEFC` class and assigns it to that global variable. Then the code you've shown will work.

Its probably not a good design for the code you've shown to be reliant on some other code to be run first, since it will fail if it gets run in the wrong order. However, using a global variable to contain a single instance of a class is not problematic in general. You just want to make sure the code that creates the instance is put somewhere that ensures it will be run before the instance is needed. For instance, the code could be put at the bottom of the `SEFC` module, or at the top of the `KCS` module.